# Spawning tasks within a for loop

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am trying to see how CPU is being utilized when I spawn a lot of tasks using the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Main Started");
    MainChild(sw).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Main ended: "+sw.Elapsed);
}

static async Task MainChild(Stopwatch sw)
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(async()=> {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Task1 completed: " + sw.Elapsed);
        }));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

I noticed that the main thread executes the :"Main Ended: " even before the tasks are executed. Why is this?

Comment: You are not spawning a lot of threads. You are starting tasks. While threads and tasks are related they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Task.Factory.StartNew` method is outdated and almost never used this days, also it [doesn't understand async delegates](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Another thing is that the `Action` delegate returns void and `async void` is a fire-and-forget type of action. This operation doesn't return Task and is not awaited.

Change `Action`:

```
tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(new Action(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 completed: " + sw.Elapsed);
}));
```

To `Func<Task>` and `Task.Run`:

```
tasks[i] = Task.Run(new Func<Task>(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task1 completed: " + sw.Elapsed);
}));
```

As delegate type is inferred by compiler we can shorten it to:

```
tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () => ...
```

Now it is working as expected and waits for all tasks to finish execution

Comment: @KirkLarkin I've added the shortened version however I wanted to emphasize the fact that in order to be awaited the delegate must return a `Task`

Comment: could you add more information about the difference between Task.Run(new Action and Task.Run(new Func<Task> ? why the first Wait doesn't block current thread while the second Wait  does?